# Control axis size matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't find a way to control the alignment of points in `matplotlib.pyplot` in order to more properly center samples within a window. Below is an example where I am plotting two averaged samples with stdev and instead of being uniformly spaced within the window, they are pushed off onto the edges of the plot.

Is there a way to better control this alignment? My code is below for reference.

```
plt.clf()
plt.errorbar(np.arange(len(rmean)),rmean,yerr=rstddev, linestyle="None", fmt='o')
plt.xlabel('Probes', fontsize=1)
plt.ylabel('VAF')
plt.title('Average VAF Along Probed Regions')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(rmean)),labels,rotation='90')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you've already know this from [Matplotlib Examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/errorbar_demo.html). Essentially, the x-axis position of your data is defined by "x", which is `np.arange(len(rmean))`. Therefore, the final visual position is related to the range of x-axis, the `xlim`. Then one potential solution is to set `xlim` by `plt.xlim([-1, len(rmean)])`. I don't have your `rmean` or `rstddev`. But testing by some fake data, I got this:
[image]
Hopefully, this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may manually set the limits on the xaxis to give more space. Here you have values of 0 and 1 on the axis, so setting e.g. `plt.xlim(-2,3)` gives you some more space.

You could also automatically assign some proportion of the axes to be left free, e.g. to get 50% margin, you'd do

```
plt.margins(x=0.5)
```